# Is there a way to integrate DataImportHandler with C#?

Tags: solr, solrnet, dataimporthandler

Just wanted to know is there any way to integrate DataImportHandler with C# application.

Currently my requirement is to get delta data from different tables and index it to solr for that i have created a stored procedure which will return me some delta rows and i am indexing them into solr using solrnet.But just wondering is there any way to achieve it using DataImportHandler with c#.

Which one of the below approaches will be best suited for indexing data into **solr**

1.Using DataImportHandler and C# if at all it is possible.

2.Using SolrNet and Ado.net

Thanks in advance